# Unable to find outdated flutter packages

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I want to upgrade outdated flutter packages, but I am getting this error:

[image: Error]

Anyone please help me with this issue.

Comment: Does github.com work if you visit the site from a browser?

Comment: github.com says Delete the ~/.pub-cache folder and retry the command. I did try but not working.

Comment: What? So when you visit https://www.github.com you are getting a message "Delete the ~/.pub-cache folder and retry the command" ??? :D

Comment: github.com is a huge platform. I was talking about exactly my issue. I searched my query and visit a github.com link in which the same issue was already been discussed. And that link says Delete the ~/.pub-cache folder and retry the command. I did try but not working.

Comment: Well, my suggestion was just because of the "unable to connect to github.com". So I wanted to make sure you could connect to "github.com" at all. There have previously been users where something have blocked their internet access to github.com.